# Cannot copy big database file from "Assets"

Tags: android, sqlite

I'm having a problem copying database from assets. When my database has a small size example 300KB it works fine. But when my database reach 2.5mb an error has been occurred. It is working fine after I have created a new AVD. Maybe its the SD card of emulator causing the error? Because when I install my app in my device it is working.

Here is what log cat says:

```
07-23 18:12:51.522: E/AndroidRuntime(866): Uncaught handler: thread main exiting due to uncaught exception
07-23 18:12:51.531: E/AndroidRuntime(866): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.frux.kfcmobile/com.frux.kfcmobile.KFCmobileActivity}: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such table: first: , while compiling: SELECT * from first
07-23 18:12:51.531: E/AndroidRuntime(866):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2496)
07-23 18:12:51.531: E/AndroidRuntime(866):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2512)
07-23 18:12:51.531: E/AndroidRuntime(866):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2200(ActivityThread.java:119)
07-23 18:12:51.531: E/AndroidRuntime(866):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1863)
07-23 18:12:51.531: E/AndroidRuntime(866):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
07-23 18:12:51.531: E/AndroidRuntime(866):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
07-23 18:12:51.531: E/AndroidRuntime(866):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4363)
07-23 18:12:51.531: E/AndroidRuntime(866):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-23 18:12:51.531: E/AndroidRuntime(866):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
07-23 18:12:51.531: E/AndroidRuntime(866):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:860)
07-23 18:12:51.531: E/AndroidRuntime(866):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618)
07-23 18:12:51.531: E/AndroidRuntime(866):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
07-23 18:12:51.531: E/AndroidRuntime(866): Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such table: first: , while compiling: SELECT * from first
07-23 18:12:51.531: E/AndroidRuntime(866):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.native_compile(Native Method)
07-23 18:12:51.531: E/AndroidRuntime(866):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.compile(SQLiteProgram.java:110)
07-23 18:12:51.531: E/AndroidRuntime(866):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:59)
07-23 18:12:51.531: E/AndroidRuntime(866):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteQuery.<init>(SQLiteQuery.java:49)
07-23 18:12:51.531: E/AndroidRuntime(866):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.query(SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.java:49)
07-23 18:12:51.531: E/AndroidRuntime(866):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQueryWithFactory(SQLiteDatabase.java:1220)
07-23 18:12:51.531: E/AndroidRuntime(866):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQuery(SQLiteDatabase.java:1193)
07-23 18:12:51.531: E/AndroidRuntime(866):  at com.frux.kfcmobile.KFCmobileActivity.onCreate(KFCmobileActivity.java:42)
07-23 18:12:51.531: E/AndroidRuntime(866):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
07-23 18:12:51.531: E/AndroidRuntime(866):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2459)
07-23 18:12:51.531: E/AndroidRuntime(866):  ... 11 more
```

Here is my DBHelper Codes:

```
public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper{

private static String DB_PATH = "/data/data/com.frux.kfcmobile/databases/";
private static String DB_NAME = "database";
private SQLiteDatabase myDataBase; 
private final Context myContext;
private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;


public DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    super(context, DB_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    this.myContext = context;


}
 public void createDataBase() throws IOException{

        boolean dbExist = checkDataBase();

        if(dbExist){
            //do nothing - database already exist
            this.getWritableDatabase();
            this.close();
        }else{

            //By calling this method and empty database will be created into the default system path
               //of your application so we are gonna be able to overwrite that database with our database.
            this.getReadableDatabase();
            this.close();
            try {

                copyDataBase();

            } catch (IOException e) {

            //throw new Error("Error copying database message");

            }
        }

    }

 private boolean checkDataBase(){

        SQLiteDatabase checkDB = null;

        try{
            String myPath = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
            checkDB = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);

        }catch(SQLiteException e){

            //database does't exist yet.

        }

        if(checkDB != null){

            checkDB.close();

        }

        return checkDB != null ? true : false;
    }



 private void copyDataBase() throws IOException{

        //Open your local db as the input stream
        InputStream myInput = myContext.getAssets().open(DB_NAME);

        // Path to the just created empty db
        String outFileName = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;

        //Open the empty db as the output stream
        OutputStream myOutput = new FileOutputStream(outFileName);

        //transfer bytes from the inputfile to the outputfile
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int length;
        while ((length = myInput.read(buffer))>0){
            myOutput.write(buffer, 0, length);
        }

        //Close the streams
        myOutput.flush();
        myOutput.close();
        myInput.close();

    }



 public void openDataBase() throws SQLException{

        //Open the database
        String myPath = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
        myDataBase = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);

    }

    @Override
    public synchronized void close() {

            if(myDataBase != null)
                myDataBase.close();

            super.close();

    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {


    }





    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {


    }
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to error your database has no table named `first`. It seems it is copied.

Comment: it has. because when the database do have a small size it works fine. but when I insert fields and data then it reach the size of 2.5mb and start the error and creating the database that the only table is android_metadata

Answer (score 1):

See the below tutorial

http://www.reigndesign.com/blog/using-your-own-sqlite-database-in-android-applications/

There is a limitation around 1.2 Mb for files in the asset folder.

If it is working fine "Because when I install my app in my device it is working." then what is your problem.

Comment: the problem is when I run the app in my emulator it cause an error

Answer (score 0):

Consider this line in your Logcat

```
Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such table: first: , while compiling: SELECT * from first
```

According to that it says there are no table called "first". But you says that it is working in Emulator :-/

Go to **DDMS** view and check the DB that you have created. Use **SQLite browser** to browse the database that you have created and export.

Comment: when i View the database it only has the android_metadata table. but when the database has a small size it copy all the table

Comment: First I try to make a new database and it works. then when I add fields and data in the same database and reach 2.5mb that's when the error starts

Comment: Why don't you put  your code here. Then we also can get an understand of the issue. The code snippet where you create the DB and insert data may be enough.

Comment: You are saying that you are "coping" the DB. If so check that you have given read/write permission in your Manifest to save data on device SD card

Comment: Yes I am able to copy the database from my assets after I reformat my pc and install a new eclipse and sdk.

Comment: In normally we are calling `DatabaseHelper` class it calls the `onCreate()` method where we create the tables. But you are creating the DB and tables separately. According to your code it is in `createDataBase()` -> `checkDataBase()` and `copyDataBase()` path. But I can't see any reference to `createDataBase()` which is the basic method to initiate the DB and table. If you are not referring that method directly from another class, call it inside the `onCreate()` method.

Comment: I just base that code in this tutorial http://www.reigndesign.com/blog/using-your-own-sqlite-database-in-android-applications/

Comment: Seems you have accepted an answer. If you have any doubt still, create an emulator with large size of storage and also the heap size is little big. Again you can use DDMS to check how heap is allocating while your application is running. Good luck :-)